# Adjust scale of the horizontal axis in a Chart with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

I am trying to create a chart with VBA, collecting data with the code from a table (not selecting directly the data in the worksheet but doing some internal calculation). My problem is that it does not draw correctly the X-axis (it should be showing just 12.19, 01.20, 02.20):

[image]

Do you know how to adjust this (as each month has a different amount of days...)?

This is my code:

```
Function ChartGenerator(mes As Double, contrato As String, kpi As String)
    Dim listax() As Double
    Dim listay() As Double
    Dim numeelem As Integer
    numeelem = 0

last_row = Worksheets("Data").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

    For i = 2 To last_row
        If Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 8).value <= mes And Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 4).value = contrato _
        And Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 5).value = kpi Then

            numeelem = numeelem + 1
        End If
    Next i

    ReDim listax(numeelem - 1)
    ReDim listay(numeelem - 1, 1)

    numeelem = 0
    For i = 2 To last_row
        If Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 8) <= mes And Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 4) = contrato _
        And Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 5) = kpi Then

            numeelem = numeelem + 1
            listax(numeelem - 1) = Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 8).value **'Those are dates**
            listay(numeelem - 1, 0) = Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 6).value
            listay(numeelem - 1, 1) = Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 7).value
        End If
    Next i

    Dim ydata As Variant
    ReDim ydata(numeelem - 1)

    Charts.Add
        With ActiveChart
            .ChartArea.ClearContents
            .ChartType = xlXYScatterLines
            .ChartStyle = 241 'para cambiar el estilo, usar este

            For k = 1 To 2
                For j = 0 To numeelem - 1
                    ydata(j) = listay(j, k - 1)
                Next j
                .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
                .SeriesCollection(k).XValues = listax
                .SeriesCollection(k).Values = ydata
                .SeriesCollection(k).Name = Worksheets("Data").Cells(1, 6 - 1 + k).value '"prueba" & i 'ID(i, 1)
                If k = 2 Then
                .SeriesCollection(k).Format.Line.DashStyle = msoLineSysDash
                End If
                    For j = 1 To numeelem
                    With .SeriesCollection(k).Points(j)
                        .ApplyDataLabels
                        .DataLabel.Text = listay(j - 1, k - 1)
                    End With
                    Next j
            Next k
            .HasTitle = True

        .Legend.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = 14
        .ChartTitle.Text = contrato & " - " & kpi
        With .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary)
        .HasTitle = True
        .AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Date"
        .AxisTitle.Font.Size = 14
        .AxisTitle.Font.Name = "calibri"
        .CategoryType = xlTimeScale
        .MinimumScale = listax(0) - 0.0000000001
        .MaximumScale = listax(numeelem - 1) + 1
        .MinorUnit = 31
        .MajorUnit = 31
        .TickLabels.NumberFormat = "mmmm-yy"
        End With
        With .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary)
        .HasTitle = True
        .AxisTitle.Text = "Amount of €"
        .AxisTitle.Font.Size = 14
        .AxisTitle.Font.Name = "calibri"
        End With

        End With

End Function
```

Comment: Are the dates that are shows on the x-axis saved in a row or a column?

Comment: If you 'create a chart with VBA' show code to us.

Comment: I added the code, do you have any idea?